# Query in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios7, message

I'm using  MFMessageComposeViewController in my application and it's working but messenger is opening within the application what i'm suppose if i want to open the Messenger outside the application.

Comment: Messenger outside the application means ..?\

Comment: when i tap on that message button Messenger window is opening but that opening in side my App window - i'm not able to post the image or-else would have posted with the Image